# "Use of unknown directive #pragma" error in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, pragma

I try to silence a deprecation warning in Xcode 12.3 using this code:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
// Use iof deprecated API
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Unfortunately I get the error message

> Use of unknown directive '#pragma'

Is there something to consider before this code works?